# Excel If Formula - Generic Error Message

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm dumbfounded as to why the if formulas in my excel work books don't work.
Something simple as =if(F2=0, TRUE, FALSE) throws a generic error "There's a problem with this formula."  Not sure where to turn in regards to this.
Column H is formatted as General.  [image]

Comment: Can you select cell with the formula, click on in and make a screenshot of what you see as a "comment" by Excel. It shows the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start writing the formula and Excel will show you the correct format. In the case below, it is using `;` for divisors. In your case it could be `,`:

[image]

Comment: Holy crap..  you're right..  For some reason, it's a pipe delimited instead of a comma that's I'm so used to using!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that you want to return a text value by using speech marks

```
=if(F2=0, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Should be

```
=if(F2=0, "TRUE", "FALSE")
```

Comment: @JK0124 - `TRUE` and `FALSE` are specific words in the English version of Excel. Thus, the `"` should not be needed.